# Alter Database to utf8 In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to Alter a database to accept `utf8_general_ci` in migration file

```
class AlterTableToArabic < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    ALTER DATABASE noswazefa_backend_development CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
  end
end
```

but when I run `rake db:migrate`, this error appears in console:

> -- utf8_general_ci()
>       rake aborted!
>       StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>       undefined local variable or method `utf8_general_ci' for # < AlterTableToArabic:0x000055e5b967b020 >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generate migration file and paste this code

```
class ConvertTablesToUtf8 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change_encoding(encoding,collation)
 connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
 tables = connection.tables
 dbname =connection.current_database
 execute <<-SQL
   ALTER DATABASE #{dbname} CHARACTER SET #{encoding} COLLATE #{collation};
 SQL
 tables.each do |tablename|
   execute <<-SQL
     ALTER TABLE #{dbname}.#{tablename} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET #{encoding} COLLATE #{collation};
   SQL
 end
 end

def change
 reversible do |dir|
   dir.up do
     change_encoding('utf8','utf8_general_ci')
   end
   dir.down do
     change_encoding('latin1','latin1_swedish_ci')
   end
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't just paste any arbitrary SQL into a migration and expect Ruby to be ok with it. Its a Ruby DSL to write SQL statements - not a magic tunnel into your database.

```
class AlterTableToArabic < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute "ALTER DATABASE noswazefa_backend_development CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
  end
end
```

In this case you should use `def up` instead of `def change` as this is not reversible.